# Accessing typescript generics keys

Tags: generics, typescript

Consider the following typescript [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20XInput%20%7B%0A%20%20xin%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20XOutput%20%7B%0A%20%20xout%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20YInput%20%7B%0A%20%20yin%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20YOutput%20%7B%0A%20%20yout%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20FMap%20%7B%0A%20%20getX%3A%20any%3B%0A%20%20getY%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20InputMap%20extends%20FMap%20%7B%0A%20%20getX%3A%20XInput%3B%0A%20%20getY%3A%20YInput%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20OutputMap%20extends%20FMap%20%7B%0A%20%20getX%3A%20XOutput%3B%0A%20%20getY%3A%20YOutput%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MethodDictionary%3CFM%2C%20MI%20extends%20FM%2C%20MO%20extends%20FM%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20private%20_methods%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20define%3CN%20extends%20keyof%20FM%3E(name%3A%20N%2C%20fn%3A%20(a%3A%20MI%5BN%5D)%20%3D%3E%20MO%5BN%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this._methods%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20fn%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20mapper%20%3D%20new%20MethodDictionary%3CFMap%2C%20InputMap%2C%20OutputMap%3E()%3B%0Amapper.define('getX'%2C%20(a%3A%20XInput)%3A%20XOutput%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20xout%3A%200%20%7D%3B%20%7D)%3B%0A):

```typescript
interface XInput { xin: number; }
interface XOutput { xout: number; }
interface YInput { yin: number; }
interface YOutput { yout: number; }

interface FMap {
  getX: any;
  getY: any;
}

interface InputMap extends FMap {
  getX: XInput;
  getY: YInput;
}

interface OutputMap extends FMap {
  getX: XOutput;
  getY: YOutput;
}

class MethodDictionary<FM, MI extends FM, MO extends FM> {
  private _methods: any = {};

  define<N extends keyof FM>(name: N, fn: (a: MI[N]) => MO[N]) {
    this._methods[name] = fn;
  }

  call<N extends keyof FM>(name: N, input: MI[N]) {
    this._methods[name](input);
  }
}

const mapper = new MethodDictionary<FMap, InputMap, OutputMap>();
mapper.define('getX', (a: XInput): XOutput => { return { xout: 0 }; });
mapper.call('getX', { xin: 0 });
```

In this example I wish to define a function mapper that takes in the name of the function and forces us to define functions that take in some input and give out some output. In this case I wish to force myself to write
the following functions:

```typescript
interface MyMethods {
   getX: (a: XInput) => XOutput;
   getY: (a: YInput) => YOutput;
}
```

I could have written the following:

```typescript
class OtherMapper<M> {
  private _methods: any = {};

  define<N extends keyof M>(name: N, fn: M[N]) {
    this._methods[name] = fn;
  }
}
```

and I would have achieved the same as above. That is, if we were to write:

```typescript
mapper.define('otherKey', ...)
```

typescript will let us know that only `getX | getY` are only allowed. If we were to change the inputs or outputs of the function it will also warn us.

But I would not have been able to write the definition for the `call` method. Do you guys see a way in which we can simplify the working example so that typescript can still warn us about the types we use and yet having a way to define a much simpler contract? That is, can we define

```typescript
interface MethodMap {
  getX: [XInput, XOutput];
  getY: [YInput, YOutput];
}
```

and use it as the only generic argument of our mapper? I wanted to write this but it doesn't work:

```typescript
class MethodDictionary<M> {
  private _methods: any = {};

  define<N extends keyof M>(name: N, fn: (a: M[N][0]) => M[N][1]) {
    this._methods[name] = fn;
  }

  call<N extends keyof M>(name: N, input: M[N][0]) {
    this._methods[name](input);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface XInput { xin: number; }
interface XOutput { xout: number; }
interface YInput { yin: number; }
interface YOutput { yout: number; }

type DictionaryFunction<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: {
    parameter: any;
    returns: any;
  }
}

class MethodDictionary<M extends DictionaryFunction<M>> {
  private _methods: any = {};

  define<N extends keyof M>(name: N, fn: (a: M[N]['parameter']) => M[N]['returns']) {
    this._methods[name] = fn;
  }

  call<N extends keyof M>(name: N, input: M[N]['parameter']) {
    this._methods[name](input);
  }
}

interface FMap {
    getX: {
        parameter: XInput,
        returns: XOutput
    };
    getY: {
        parameter: YInput,
        returns: YOutput,
    };
}

const mapper = new MethodDictionary<FMap>();
mapper.define('getX', (a: XInput): XOutput => { return { xout: 0 }; });
mapper.call('getX', { xin: 0 });
```